# Freemarker: find one result in array of objects

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, freemarker, template-engine

I have array like below:

```
<#assign services = [
{'id': '1', 'name': 'AAAA'},
{'id': '22', 'name': 'BBBB'}
]>
```

I know the id .. example **22**. I need something like this:

```
${services[2].name} // print BBBB
```

i tried this but without result

```
${services[services.type?seq_index_of(22)].name}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

If you can, pass the services model as a map instead of array. Otherwise you can iterate through the services to find the right one. If you need to use it multiple times then you can abstract the logic into a macro like this:

```
<#macro getServiceName id serviceList>
    <#list serviceList as service>
        <#if service['id']==id>
            ${service['name']}
            <#break/>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</#macro>

<#assign services = [
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'AAAA'},
    {'id': '22', 'name': 'BBBB'}
]>


<#assign serviceId="22"/>
service ${serviceId} name = <@getServiceName id=serviceId serviceList=services/>
```

Comment: thank you ... macros are good idea, i like it... i am a noob in freemarker

Answer (score 2):

You can loop on the `services` array.

```
<#assign services = [
{'id': '1', 'name': 'AAAA'},
{'id': '2', 'name': 'BBBB'},
{'id': '22', 'name': 'CCCC'},
{'id': '23', 'name': 'DDDD'}
]>

<#list services as service>
   <#if service.id == '22'>
        Result: ${service.name}
    </#if>
</#list>
```

Comment: thank you for help but this solution i have now but i asked if i can do it better